# What are the awards for which Netflix original movies are eligible?

Tags: netflix, awards

What are the awards, that movies made for **Netflix** and **Amazon Prime Video** exclusively eligible for? They are eligible for Academy awards if they follow the rules of running in theatre for seven days. What are the major awards for which such movies are eligible? State examples of nomination or the winning of awards.

Comment: As the answer to your previous question highlighted why they are not eligible for Oscars, then I would say that they could qualify for any other award that does not have such strict criteria. Empire Magazine's awards are directly vote for by the readers so I cannot see why they would not include Netflix productions, just for starters.

Comment: This is baffling, somewhat; Netflix/Amazon films are eligible for, and have [been nominated for Oscars in the past](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/01/netflix-oscars-2018-mudbound-nominations)...?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Read the article: "Beginning last November, the studio screened the movie in theaters for five weeks". Netflix simply abided by the Oscar rules.

Comment: "These movies are not released in theaters" This is simply not true for all.

Comment: [Oscar related](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/90aa_doc_features.pdf)

Comment: From what I've seen to date, there are many that are eligible for the [Golden Raspberry Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Awards).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually for any film to be nominated for major awards like the Academy Awards or the Golden Globes, they need to have at least a limited release in theatres.

In 2017, Netflix released *Okja* and *Meyerowitz Stories: New and Selected*, in limited release in theatres. The criteria is according to the awards.

As mentioned in the AMPAS rule book :

> for a qualifying run of at least seven consecutive days, during which period screenings must occur at least three times daily, with at least one screening beginning between 6 p.m. and 10 p.m. daily"

**These criteria must be met.**

*Fun Fact:* Tommy Wiseau paid the cinema a lot of bucks to keep *The Room* running for seven days in order to make it eligible for the Oscars.